# What does the PHP version string "PHP 5.2.0-8+etch16" mean?

Tags: linux, php, debian-etch

Currently doing a version check for a minimum required PHP version, I came across some servers that say their PHP version (checked with [`phpversion`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php)) is:

```
PHP 5.2.0-8+etch16
```

Since I'm a Windows guy and no Linux/PHP guy, I failed to find meaningful results for the `-8` and `+etch16` parts.

**My two questions are:**

- What does the `-8` mean?
- What does the `+etch16` mean?

(I'm assuming that in my above example the actual core installed PHP version is `5.2.0`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are local flags that indicate the specific packager's internal tracking of different builds they've made from the same PHP release. Likely this is their 8th release of PHP 5.2.0 and it includes version 16 of a set of patches (or build flags, or options, or whatever customization they've applied) for Debian Etch.

Comment: Also, Debian Etch is seriously ancient, and so is its PHP ... I would say it is not suitable for generic internet facing applications due to security problems ...